# Having trouble implementing a sort array function in mips assembly language

Tags: arrays, sorting, assembly, mips

I've been assigned to implement a sort array function that sorts the contents of an array in numerical order from smallest to largest. The array is as follows:

```
testArray:
        .word 9
        .word 8
        .word 7
        .word 4
        .word 5
        .word 6
        .word 3
        .word 2
        .word 1
        .word 0
```

When I send this array to be sorted my output comes out as so:

```
A[0] = 9
A[1] = 8
A[2] = 7
A[3] = 4
A[4] = 5
A[5] = 6
A[6] = 3
A[7] = 2
A[8] = 1
A[9] = 0
Sorting Array Contents.
A[0] = 8
A[1] = 7
A[2] = 4
A[3] = 5
A[4] = 6
A[5] = 3
A[6] = 2
A[7] = 1
A[8] = 0
A[9] = 9
Program terminated.
```

This is the algorithm that I am using to sort the array contents

```
void sortArray(int A[], int entryCount) {
  int i;
  int j;
  int temp;
  for (i = entryCount - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
      if (A[j + 1] < A[j]) {
        temp = A[j];
        A[j] = A[j + 1];
        A[j + 1] = temp;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My conversion to mips is as follows:

```
# Temporary registers
#
#   $t0 = address of teststring
#   $t1 = n
#   $t2 = i
#   $t3 = j
#   $t4 = temp
#   $t5 = A[j]
sortArray:

    move            $t0, $a0            # Load array address into $t0
    move            $t1, $a1            # $t1 = n
    move            $t2, $zero          # set i = 0
    move            $t3, $zero          # set j = 0
    move            $t4, $zero          # set temp = 0
    move            $t2, $t1            # set i = entrycount
    b           condition_test

condition_test:
    subi            $t2, $t2, 1         # i--
    bgtz            $t2, condition_test2    
    b           end

condition_test2:    
    blt         $t3, $t2, condition_test3   # j < i
    b           condition_test

condition_test3:
    lw          $t5, 0($t0)         # A[j]
    addi        $t0, $t0, 4
    lw          $t6, 0($t0)         # A[j+1]
    sub         $t0, $t0, 4         
    blt         $t6, $t5, loop_top      # (A[j+1] < A[j])
    b           condition_test2

loop_top:
    move        $t4, $t5            # temp = A[j]
    sw          $t6, 0($t0)         # A[j] = A[j+1]
    add         $t0, $t0, 4 
    sw          $t4, 0($t0)         # A[j+1] = temp
    addi        $t3, $t3, 1         # j++
    b           condition_test2

end:
    jr          $ra
```

Hopefully someone can shed some light on what I have done wrong with my conversion. Thanks.

Comment: For one thing, you don't have the `j = 0` of the inner loop inside the outer loop.

Comment: Learn how to use a debugger. Step through the program and figure out where its behavior is different from what you expect.